# Должен ли я поддерживать нестандартные конфигурации?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, поковырялся я на форумах, где люди делятся лайфхаками по использованию андроида. Рут права, замена DPI, удаление зависимости от гугла, редактирование build.prop и т.п. Вообщем, любые действия, превращающие андроид в ненастоящий смартфон, который от настоящих отличается.

Сам менял DPI и в некоторых приложениях происходили вылеты, а в логах что-то говорилось про dp. 
Или например, нужно проверить есть ли файл в системе. А юзер как-то сделал, чтобы этот файл лежал в другом месте, но так же работал. Выходит я получу ложный результат. А если будет потребность в удалении? Я вообще убью смартфон и меня забанят?

Или например, реклама от гугла, всякие сервисы от гугла, удалял гаппсы и ставил игры - некоторые вылетали.

Так вот, я обязан следить за тем, чтобы приложение работало так же хорошо на этих "роботах"? Или нет?

Comment: *"юзер как-то сделал, чтобы этот файл лежал в другом месте, но так же работал"* -- значит, неправильно вы проверяете, раз система работает, а ваша программа нет. Но для ясности хотелось бы конкретных примеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нужно понимать, что вы пишите приложения для Android устройств, который предоставляют разные производители. Вот если что-то будет не так работать у одного производителя(бывает такое у HTC, Samsung), то вы должны это поддерживать. Но то? что делают люди со своими смартфонами это уже не ваша проблема. Ибо нечего! Это уже будет считаться нестандартным устройством.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, Вы не обязаны. Но если Вы хотите охватить данную аудиторию пользователей, то, очевидно, лучше разобраться.